# Cellular network name appearing twice

Tags: mobile-network, 7.1-nougat

The network operator name is being displayed like:

> VODAFONE IN – Vodafone IN

[[Screenshot]](https://s20.postimg.org/anzxpuzbx/Screenshot_20170313_203818.png) (left-top)

Instead of appearing twice, can it be made to appear only once?

Or can it be removed?

Without rooting.

Nexus 6P - Android 7.1.1

Edit: The device is single SIM. I tried in another device and there too the network operator name is being displayed twice so seeming to me fault of the network operator.

Comment: Guess your device is Dual-SIM? Afraid without rooting that's not possible. If the device is rooted, there are several Xposed modules – but then again, Xposed AFAIK is not (yet?) available for Nougat. Only thing left then: Take out one SIM. Admittedly, not a real solution to consider :)

Comment: @Izzy The device is single SIM. I tried in another device and there too the network operator name is being displayed twice so seeming to me fault of the network operator.

Comment: If it happens on a single-SIM device, that indeed seems to be an error on the operator's end. I'd check with one of their shops (to make sure it's not the SIM), they should have several devices displaying the name "as set up".